# Would a game with a man walking on a planet be a tile based game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say there was a game, where you stay on a single screen (unless you pass the level), and you are a man walking around in space.

It seems like a tile based game to me, the only catch is that when you move, it has some physics at play, meaning the more you press up, the faster you move and the longer it takes to slow down.

And you also keep moving even if you stop pressing the arrow keys as you have gained momentum.

thoughts?

how would I handle the movement of the man based on momentum etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to use Cocos2d, start with this

[image]

[Learn iPhone and iPad cocos2d Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233036)

It has an example in the chapter "Your First Game" which covers Velocity calculations and controlling a players movement using these calculations.

Also as bbum mentioned 
[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) has some great tutorials and is really educating developers on some interesting topics.

He also has co-authored a book which is available for pre-order.
[image]

[Learning Cocos2D: A Hands-On Guide to Building iOS Games with Cocos2D, Box2D, and Chipmunk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321735625)

Answer (score 2):

Sure;  it could easily be a tile based game and there are multiple examples of exactly that.   Heck;  Super Mario is a tile based game -- the level and backgrounds are all tile based layouts -- with the characters -- also tiles -- moving based on a very simple physics model.

Cocos2d is a tile based game engine that also has support for several physics engines.

Ray Wenderlich has written an excellent series of tutorials on uses of cocos2d.  Here is one that [includes physics to model a bouncing ball](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls).

Comment: There are also the box2D and chipmunk collision and physics engines that integrate well with Cocos2d.

Answer (score -2):

Either you have a game like [lunar lander](http://science.discovery.com/tv/space-week/mission-control/games/lunar_lander.html), where the position of the man is based on physics, or you have a tile based game.  You cannot have both at the same time.

Comment: Not true; cocos2d -- a tile based gaming engine -- has support for multiple physics engines and there is nothing preventing you from having motion based on physics in a tile based game.   "Tile Based" often refers to the means via which the "map" is managed/drawn, not a limitation of motion.

Comment: @bbum:  What is the point of tiles if physics determines the position of the man?  Just because something can be done, doesn't mean that it should be done.

Comment: One of the most common means of writing a game is to used tile based maps, tile based overlays, etc... while then laying characters on top that move decoupled from the map.  A number of the games on this page (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/games/) are exactly that;  tile based w/free motion on top.  So are many of the tower defense games, some with physics, too.

Comment: tiles refers more to how the graphics are done and drawn, and less to the static representation of movement.  Zelda for the SNES is a perfect example of where your hero lived on a TileMap, but did not move in static chunky squares like a chessboard.